# Data step issue in sas enterprise guide

Tags: sas

I need to write data step query in sas where i need to give sequence numbers to a column starting from a particular number.

For example right now my table looks like this:

```
Column 1   Column 2
abc         book1
xyz         book2
zex         book3
```

I want my table to look like this:

```
Column 1   Column 2    Column3
abc         book1      151   
xyz         book2      152
zex         book3      153
```

How to add `Column 3` with a sequence number staring from a particular number?

Answer (score 0):

How about this

```
data have;
input Column1 $ Column2 $;
datalines;
abc         book1
xyz         book2
zex         book3
;

data want;
   do Column3 = 150 by 1 until (lr);
      set have end=lr;
      output;
   end;
run;
```